# How to switch between two numbers by pressing button?

Tags: java, if-statement, libgdx

I need to switch between two `numbers` by pressing `"q"`.

First press:

```
number = 1;
```

Second press:

```
number = 2;
```

Third press:

```
number = 1;
```

Fourth press:

```
number = 2;
```

e
t
c

Got `method` and `variable`:

```
 private static int counter = 0;

 private int switchNumbers() {
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.Q)){
            counter = 1;
        }
        if (counter == 1 && Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.Q)){
            counter = 2;
        }
        if (counter == 2 && Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.Q)){
            counter = 1;
        }

      return counter;
    }
```

`variable counter` always equals 1.

How can achieve it `(switching numbers)`?

Comment: Use else if block after first if block.

Comment: "Use else if block" - not working

Comment: in that case variable change from 0 to 1 only once and remain at 1 position

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Where does libgdx come into this? I'd suggest, on each key press, just to set number = 3 - number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can check what is the current value of counter if its 1 then put 2 else put 1:

by a `ternary opeator`:

```
private static int counter = 0;

private int switchNumbers() {
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.Q)) {
        counter = counter == 1 ? 2 : 1;
    }
    return counter;
}
```

or simple using `if-else`:

```
private int switchNumbers() {
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.Q)) {
        if(counter == 1) {
            counter = 2;
        } else {
            counter = 1;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```